# MariaDB Query EXISTS and BETWEEN

Tags: mariadb, json-table

I want to Filter about Events where the Distance is between a Range

I use 10.6.15-MariaDB

DB Structure is like:

```
event_id, event_title, event_distances
1, event1, [{"order":0,"value":21}]
2, event2, [{"order":0,"value":8}]
3, event3, [{"order":0,"value":10}]
4, event4, [{"order":0,"value":5},{"order":1,"value":10},{"order":2,"value":21}]
```

I try with Query:

```
SELECT events.event_title, event_distances 
FROM events 
WHERE 
EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1 
    FROM JSON_TABLE(event_distances, '$[*]' COLUMNS (distance_value FLOAT PATH '$.value')) AS distances 
    WHERE distances.distance_value BETWEEN 9 AND 22
) 
ORDER BY events.event_id ASC;
```

but I get strange returns, with value between 0 and 22 I get all Events (which is correct, but for example with value between 20 and 22 no rows returns.

Maybe someone can help me to find the problem on my Query?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately its a current bug [MDEV-30623](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-30623) that has not been fixed yet.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the Info, so i can stop struggling around and wait for a solution

Comment: Sorry for your struggles. Asking does pay off. And now there's an additional case for the bug priority. Good work around with JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked around the Bug for now by using a JOIN

```
SELECT events.* FROM events JOIN JSON_TABLE(event_distances, '$[*]' COLUMNS (distance_value FLOAT PATH '$.value')) AS distances ON distances.distance_value BETWEEN $minDistance AND $maxDistance
```

For now i can't see any Problems with this...

Comment: I don't see any problems. I tend to always go JOIN syntax over EXISTS anyway.